# Theme not being applied

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am simply trying to change the background color for an activity, however nothing has changed.

Here is the relevant XML:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="STBTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pedro.stb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/STBTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:theme="@style/STBTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Furthermore, I'm using Eclipse, and by changing the theme in the activity's xml, it does not change in the graphical layout.

Any help?

**Edit**
Got it to work. Have to clean the project before reloading the layout. Very annoying...

Comment: Have you set any color or theme in the XML layout which is used in this activity?

Comment: @Dharmendra Where in the activity'se XML should I add that?

Answer (score 3):

i had check your code its ok .

try  `<item name="android:Background">#ccff33</item>`

instead of your `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>.`

and you have write `android:theme="@style/STBTheme" >` in application as well as activity also.

Just write in application  tag .

Hope you will get your output now.

Comment: Changing to android:Background gives an error. Putting that tag in the application only does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Open the preview of your activity and Click on the circled button as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhKGW.png)
2. [Type the name of your custom theme and Click 'OK' as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t05NT.png)
3. In Manifest file add the attribute android:theme=".YourTheme" to the required Activity

You will have the theme of the current activity changed.

I dont know why Android Studio acts like it's drunk sometimes. I have two projects with same target,minimum SDK active. One of them had the splash screen theme implemented correctly, the other just wont show until I found this workaround.